# Porcentagem de cor com php

Tags: php, imagem

Fiz um site de imobiliária, e estou tentando deixar o mais automatizado possível o upload de imagens dos imóveis centralizadas em imagens de tamanho único com fundo branco até ai blz, mas cheguei na parte dos banners que é feito automático como o sorteio de imóveis tem muitas fotos com os lados brancos.

Minha ideia foi **selecionar imagens** que não tenham esse fundo branco **onde a porcentagem de branco seja a menor possível**, rodaria um php colocaria essa porcentagem na tabela de fotos e faria um `where` nessa campo.

Teria algo em php que consiga ler uma imagem e determinar qual cor que mais aparece ou quanto de uma cor "branca" aparece nessa imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [ColorExtractor](http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract):

Essa classe pode ser usada para extrair as cores mais comuns usadas nas imagens.

Pode abrir um arquivo de imagem no formato GIF, JPEG ou PNG. Em seguida, ele percorre a imagem e retorna uma matriz com a porcentagem dos tons de cores mais usados.

```
<?php

require_once 'colors.inc.php';
$ex=new GetMostCommonColors();
$num_results=20;
$reduce_brightness=1;
$reduce_gradients=1;
$delta=24;


$colors=$ex->Get_Color( 'image.png', $num_results, $reduce_brightness, $reduce_gradients, $delta);


echo json_encode($colors, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Resultados convertidos em JSON:

```
{
"300090": 0.0034146341463415,
"ffffff": 0.53479674796748,
"6000f0": 0.16308943089431,
"f0f0f0": 0.052682926829268,
"a878f0": 0.032520325203252,
"d8d8f0": 0.029756097560976,
"4890f0": 0.02260162601626,
"f0fff0": 0.021463414634146,
"7848f0": 0.01869918699187,
"c0a8f0": 0.018211382113821,
"6018f0": 0.018048780487805,
"48c0f0": 0.01609756097561,
"9060f0": 0.013983739837398,
"fffff0": 0.013658536585366,
"a8f0f0": 0.008130081300813,
"f0f0ff": 0.0079674796747967,
"f0ffff": 0.0066666666666667,
"48ffd8": 0.0063414634146341,
"78ffd8": 0.0027642276422764,
"a878ff": 0.0022764227642276
}
```

Requisitos:

```
PHP 4.0.2 ou maior  
GD2 image library
```